# Is there any way to Stream Map Filter & Map back to original object in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there any way to Stream the list --> map --> filter --> map back to original object type of list?

There is solution if we are doing it using foreach as below:

```
List<Query> updatedQueries = getUpdatedQueries();

List<Query> finalQueries = new ArrayList<>();
updatedQueries.forEach(query -> {

    Period period = getPeriodRequest(query);
    boolean isValidPeriod = periodService.validatePeriodicity(period);
    if(isValidPeriod &&  isMandatory(period)){
        finalQueries.add(query);
    }

});
```

But is there any way to do it using following way ?

```
List<Query> updatedQueries = getUpdatedQueries();

List<Query> finalQueries = updatedQueries
        .stream()
        .map(this::getPeriodRequest) //returns the object of type Period
        .filter(period->periodService.validatePeriodicity(period))
        .filter(this::isMandatory)
        //is any way we can map back to Query object (without any object translation  function)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: That's not possible. You should not have mapped it in the first place. You should operate on `Query` the whole time.

Comment: You'll be forced to use lambda expressions rather than method references.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one

```
List<Query> finalQueries = updatedQueries
    .stream().filter(query->{
        Period period = getPeriodRequest(query);
        return periodService.validatePeriodicity(period )&& isMandatory(period))
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: It makes sense to what I'm doing in foreach to do inside filter. Thanks for this approach. Better than foreach.

Answer (score 6):

You can expand the `filter` as:

```
    List<Query> finalQueries = updatedQueries
            .stream()
            .filter(query -> {
                Period period = getPeriodRequest(query);
                return periodService.validatePeriodicity(period) && isMandatory(period);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all your actual result is of type `List<Period> finalQueries` because of that `map(this::getPeriodRequest)`. Simply use some "longer" lambdas:

```
 updatedQueries.stream()
               .filter(q -> periodService.validatePeriodicity(q.getPeriodRequest()))
               .filter(q -> isMandatory(q.getPeriodRequest()))
               .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

You can even compress those two `filter`s into a single one and read `q.getPeriodRequest()` only once if you really wanted to.

Or you could map to a `SimpleEntry` for example:

```
 updatedQueries.stream()
               .map(x -> new SimpleEntry<>(x, x.getPeriodRequest()))
               .filter(e -> periodService.validatePeriodicity(e.getValue()))
               .filter(e -> isMandatory(e.getValue()))
               .map(Entry::getKey)
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `getPeriodRequest()` is getting called two times, which is heavier operation in terms of performance. I though about this solution, but it's expensive.

Comment: @AshwinK so what if it is called two times? it's a getter only. If you care _that_ much about performance, you should not use a Stream to begin with and stick with what you already have

Comment: Good addition @Eugene, this may be a crucial part in understanding how and when to use `Stream`s. Alone their creation may be tens to hundreds of times slower than just using a simple loop, let alone their iteration.

Comment: @Lino if they are the hot-spot though and JIT kicks in - the difference is tiny btw

Comment: @Eugene agreed, but I guess that this is a one time operation, which yields a rather static result. So JIT would probably not really optimize the whole thing. But as said, now I'm just guessing

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to store original object somehow.

Like this

```
class Pair<A, B> {
    A a;
    B b;
    // constructors and getters skipped
}
```

Then you can do following:

```
list.stream()
   .map(x -> new Pair<>(x, getOtherObject()))
   .filter(x -> checkOther(x.getB()))
   .map(Pair::getA)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use `Stream`s in the first place?

```
updatedQueries.removeIf(query-> {
    Period period = getPeriodRequest(query);
    return !periodService.validatePeriodicity(period) || !isMandatory(period));
});
```

This removes all elements from `updatedQueries` which don't match the filter. Behaves the same, but doesn't introduce a new `List`.

The best approach would probably using just a simple `for`-loop if you care about performance:

```
for (Iterator<Query> it = updatedQueries.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    Period period = getPeriodRequest(it.next());
    if(!periodService.validatePeriodicity(period) || !isMandatory(period))) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```