# Implementing firstGreatVolumeCar() method with using stream api

Tags: java, java-stream

i am so stuck with this problem. The problem is that i cannot write working method with stream api. Task is This method returns the first car whose engine size is greater than 3.0.
Use Stream API.
i wrote method which returns double but i cant rewrite method which returns Car class

```
    public Car firstGreatVolumeCar(){
        return cars.stream()
                .map(Car::getEngineVolume)
                .filter(greatVolume -> greatVolume > 3.0)
                .findFirst()
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to Stream Map Filter & Map back to original object in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56034518/is-there-any-way-to-stream-map-filter-map-back-to-original-object-in-java-8)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return the `Car` you have not to map `Car` into `double` (because from the moment you `map` a class to another type, all subsequent operations will be based on that type), but you have to keep the `Car` through stream flow.

```
public Car firstGreatVolumeCar(){
    return cars.stream()
            .filter(car -> car.getEngineVolume() > 3.0)
            .findFirst().orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: It's not always necessary to return a `null`, for instance in this example it really reads well to understand that the value is *absent* if nothing matches, which hints towards the usage of `Optional<Car` as returned from `findFirst`.

Comment: @Naman True, though given that the question already had a method with a signature returning a `Car`, the `orElse(null)` response is appropriate for answers to this specific question.

Comment: @M.Justin Yes, my suggestion was to improve the existing code on top of the question asked.